# Does anyone know of a .NET library that calculates the inverse erf() function in the normal distribution?

Tags: c#, .net, math

NET library that calculates the inverse erf() function in the normal distribution?

Do you know of any framework that include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/specialfunctions/distributions/normal.php) may give you what you want.  Available commercial or GPL in [several versions](http://www.alglib.net/download.php) including .NET (C#, 100% managed code).